# Что означает двойное многоточие при определении списка аргументов в шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, function-overloading

Объясните пожалуйста, что означает данная конструкция:

```
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes......)>
    : public true_type { };
```

А именно, в списке параметров ф-ии с 6-ю точками `_ArgTypes......`

Поясню:

Есть шаблон, перегруженный специализациями, для определения того что аргумент является функцией:

```
  template<typename>
    struct is_function
    : public false_type { };

  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)> //ф-я передается
    // по значению (как функц. объект) или по указателю
    // если _Res классическая ф-я
    : public true_type { };

  // а здесь передается по ссылке, функц. объект
  template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
    struct is_function<_Res(_ArgTypes...) &>
    : public true_type { };
```

Понятно что ф-ии могут иметь произвольное кол-во аргументов (от нуля до какого-то числа, возможно ограниченного только размером стека, это не важно) - это всё понятно, а вот синтаксис с `......` не понятен, и к сожалению в литературе и гугле не смог найти ответа на свой вопрос.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете почитать мою [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/01/18/template-innovations.aspx), которая как раз этой теме(variadic templates) посвящена.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Три точки - variadic templates, еще три точки - переменное количество аргументов.

(примерно перевожу [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token-i-e-double-ellipsis-operator-on-paramet)) Т.е. на этапе компиляции шаблон получает переменное количество шаблонных аргументов, после этого, вдобавок, инстанцированные методы/функции получают возможность принимать произвольное количество аргументов в стиле языка C.

`......` можно записать как `..., ...` - что более читабельно, кстати.

на английском многоточие называется ellipsis ...

google://c++ ellipsis template recursion

вкратце - используется для передачи произвольного количества аргументов шаблону на этапе компиляции.

почитать здесь: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ) но немного не понимаю, разве _Res(_ArgTypes...) не предполагает что в _ArgTypes будут разнотипные элементы? например вот тут в printf шаблонной - вроде же разные http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/08/variadic-templates.html

Comment: вопрос тоже норм, я хоть и учу плюсы джва года, но аж шесть точек впервые встретил

Comment: @ИльяЛесной http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625600/what-is-the-meaning-of-token-i-e-double-ellipsis-operator-on-paramet